# How to reference a pipeline resource by id/file name instead of name?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Assuming an AzureDevOps YAML pipeline pipeline-a.yml:

```
(...)

resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: pip-b
      source: \Some\UI\Folder\UI-Based-Name-For-Pipeline-B

(...)
```

Here, I have linked to a resource of pipeline b.

The problem is, that source is the name of the pipeline in the UI "\Some\UI\Folder\UI-Based-Name-For-Pipeline-B".

This name and location can change over time.

However, when I start a pipeline in an old branch, the set of pipelines that link to each other should be consistent and work no matter how I rename them in the UI.

So is it possible to link to the yaml file name  or a given Id of the source pipeline or anything that is consistent with the state of the repository at a given time and does not rely on the state of the UI?

E.g. (pseudo code):

Pipeline B

```
(...)

id: my-custom-id-for-pipeline-b

(...)
```

Pipeline A:

```
(...)

resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: pip-b
      source: my-custom-id-for-pipeline-b

(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this doc about [Pipeline Resources schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-pipelines-pipeline?view=azure-pipelines):

```
pipelines:
- pipeline: string # Required as first property. ID of the pipeline resource.
  project: string # Project for the source; defaults to current project.
  source: string # Name of the pipeline that produces the artifact.
  xxx
```

> Name of the pipeline that produces the artifact. If the pipeline is contained in a folder, include the folder name, including the leading , for example \security pipelines\security-lib-ci. This property is not case sensitive and does not need quotes if the name include spaces. The folder path must be specified if there are multiple pipelines with the same name.

The source field only supports defining the Pipeline name for the time being.

I am afraid that there is no such method to reference pipeline resource by id/file name instead of name.

I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report this feature.

**Update:**

jaw has created a Suggestion ticket based on the requirement: [Support self-contained pipeline reference ids for resources](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Support-self-contained-pipeline-referenc/10592593)

Comment: I read the docs but I was hoping to have something overlooked. Thanks for the feedback anyhow. I will suggest a feature!

Comment: @jaw After you creating the feature request, you can share the link here.  This will be helpful to other users who has the same requirement.

Comment: Added Feature request: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Support-self-contained-pipeline-referenc/10592593

Comment: @jaw Thanks for your sharing. I have upvoted the great feature request and updated my answer to include the suggestion ticket. I will update the answer if the function is launched in the future.